# CORS error when calling API multiple times using a loop

Tags: angular, api, loops, cors

I've been calling the same API but with different `id`s using loop.

However I get a **CORS error**.

This is more of an overview of what my code looks like:

```js
getRequest(id:string) {
    return this.http.get(url+id, options);
}
```

```js
tableOfIds = [...];

storeData = [];
tableOfIds.forEach(id => {
    this.serv.getRequest(id).subscribe(elements => {
        storeData.push(elements);
    });
});
```

Is there a way I can call a GET request (multiple times, with different parameters) without getting a CORS error?

Comment: The CORS error is very unlikely to be caused by your loop (doesn't matter if calling once or multiple times if Cross-Origin-Request)

Comment: Is the API rate limited?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't believe so

Comment: So if some requests get through and then others don't... rate limits are one possibility if it is a public api. Is it public or one you control?

Comment: @charlietfl I can control. I've noticed some requests actually pass, but after a certain number of them, the CORS come.

Comment: Maybe you need to throttle the requests. How many are you making roughly? Might want to check server logs also

Comment: @charlietfl I've been making more than 21 requests

Comment: That's not many unless the processing server side is really intensive

Comment: I looked at it more in-depth. It isn't a CORs issue, when I turned it off I got a 400 error. How I'm calling the api is the problem. I believe I have to write it asynchronously

Comment: Found the error. Appended the headers. It's fixed now. Used Set instead of append

Answer (score -2):

CORS are Cross-Origin Resource Sharing used in controlling api calls from unfamiliar domains, is highly unlikely that it is caused by the loop. Check how to bypass cors in your application or tell the backend person to enable CORS in his app.